# How should I map over Maybe List?

Tags: functional-programming, monads, elm, option-type, sanctuary

I came away from [Professor Frisby's Mostly Adequate Guide to Functional Programming](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/) with what seems to be a misconception about Maybe.

I believe:

```
map(add1, Just [1, 2, 3])
// => Just [2, 3, 4]
```

My feeling coming away from the aforementioned guide is that `Maybe.map` should try to call `Array.map` on the array, essentially returning `Just(map(add1, [1, 2, 3])`.

When I tried this using [Sanctuary](https://sanctuary.js.org/)'s Maybe type, and more recently [Elm](http://elm-lang.org/)'s Maybe type, I was disappointed to discover that neither of them support this (or, perhaps, I don't understand how they support this).

In Sanctuary,

```
> S.map(S.add(1), S.Just([1, 2, 3]))
! Invalid value

add :: FiniteNumber -> FiniteNumber -> FiniteNumber
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                            1

1)  [1, 2, 3] :: Array Number, Array FiniteNumber, Array NonZeroFiniteNumber, Array Integer, Array ValidNumber

The value at position 1 is not a member of ‘FiniteNumber’.
```

In Elm,

```
> Maybe.map sqrt (Just [1, 2, 3])
-- TYPE MISMATCH --------------------------------------------- repl-temp-000.elm

The 2nd argument to function `map` is causing a mismatch.

4|   Maybe.map sqrt (Just [1, 2, 3])
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `map` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    Maybe Float

But it is:

    Maybe (List number)
```

Similarly, I feel like I should be able to treat a `Just(Just(1))` as a `Just(1)`. On the other hand, my intuition about `[[1]]` is completely the opposite. Clearly, `map(add1, [[1]])` should return `[NaN]` and not `[[2]]` or any other thing.

In Elm I was able to do the following:

```
> Maybe.map (List.map (add 1)) (Just [1, 2, 3])
Just [2,3,4] : Maybe.Maybe (List number)
```

Which is what I want to do, but not how I want to do it.

How should one map over Maybe List?

Comment: in Haskell there's a Functor instance defined for the [*composition of two Functors*](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.0/base-4.9.1.0/Data-Functor-Compose.html), so that `fmap` works two levels deep, inside the composed Functor. After `import Data.Functor.Compose`,  `getCompose $ fmap (1+) $ Compose $ Just [1,2,3]` returns `Just [2,3,4]`. `Compose`/`getCompose` are just helpers for the type system.

Comment: Haskell has everything, eh!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Chad mentioned, you want to transform values nested within *two* functors.

Let's start by mapping over each individually to get comfortable:

```
> S.map(S.toUpper, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ']

> S.map(Math.sqrt, S.Just(64))
Just(8)
```

Let's consider the general type of map:

```
map :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Now, let's specialize this type for the two uses above:

```
map :: (String -> String) -> Array String -> Array String

map :: (Number -> Number) -> Maybe Number -> Maybe Number
```

So far so good. But in your case we want to map over a value of type `Maybe (Array Number)`. We need a function with this type:

```
:: Maybe (Array Number) -> Maybe (Array Number)
```

If we map over `S.Just([1, 2, 3])` we'll need to provide a function which takes `[1, 2, 3]`—the inner value—as an argument. So the function we provide to `S.map` must be a function of type `Array (Number) -> Array (Number)`. `S.map(S.add(1))` is such a function. Bringing this all together we arrive at:

```
> S.map(S.map(S.add(1)), S.Just([1, 2, 3]))
Just([2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Hey! You're the guy! :) God bless stackoverflow.

Comment: Months later, I get it! The function `add1` is `number -> number`, and map lifts add1 into `Maybe number -> Maybe number`. I was trying to apply a function that accepts and argument of `Maybe number` to a value of type `List number`. That won't work! In your last example you first lift `add1` to be `F number -> F number` and then lift it to be `Maybe F number -> Maybe F number`, and finally apply it to a value of type `Maybe F number`.

Comment: It's really cool that I can use `S.map(S.add(1))` to create a function `F number -> F number` and then apply that one function to both `S.Just(1)` and `[1, 2, 3]` even though they have different types! One is `Maybe number` and `List number`. The magic of polymorphism!

Answer (score 7):

You have two functors to deal with: `Maybe` and `List`. What you're looking for is some way to combine them. You can simplify the Elm example you've posted by function composition:

```elm
> (Maybe.map << List.map) add1 (Just [1, 2, 3])
Just [2,3,4] : Maybe.Maybe (List number)
```

This is really just a short-hand of the example you posted which you said was not *how* you wanted to do it.

Sanctuary has a [`compose`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#compose) function, so the above would be represented as:

```js
> S.compose(S.map, S.map)(S.add(1))(S.Just([1, 2, 3]))
Just([2, 3, 4])
```

> Similarly, I feel like I should be able to treat a `Just(Just(1))` as a `Just(1)`

This can be done using the [`join`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/maybe-extra/4.0.0/Maybe-Extra#join) from the `elm-community/maybe-extra` package.

```elm
join (Just (Just 1)) == Just 1
join (Just Nothing)  == Nothing
join Nothing         == Nothing
```

Sanctuary has a [`join`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#join) function as well, so you can do the following:

```js
S.join(S.Just(S.Just(1))) == Just(1)
S.join(S.Just(S.Nothing)) == Nothing
S.join(S.Nothing)         == Nothing
```